# Angular 8 error “Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1”

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest

I am learning Angular and I have this scenario in one of my services

```
agree(id: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders('Content-Type: application/json'); 
    return this.HttpClient.put(`${this.apiUrl}/agree/`, JSON.stringify(id), {headers});
  }
```

This approach worked without issues as expected...but I realized that to pass the userId is not a Best Practice, instead I use the HttpContext.User to take user Id property on my ASP.Net Core Web API, so I changed my method.

```
agree() {
    return this.HttpClient.put(`${this.apiUrl}/agreeEula/`);
  }
```

Now I have this issue

“Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1”

I will appreciate any suggestion, Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just send a null as the second parameter and a null for the third or empty object if not.

Comment: you are making put call without body and header, header is optional but you need to provide body, and better to provide header Content-Type='application/json'

Comment: Thank you guys for your fast suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the signature for HttpClient.put

```
put(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType: "arraybuffer"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<ArrayBuffer>
```

In case the body in optional, you can pass {} or null as the second argument after the url.

Read more at - https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `null` or `{}` for the 2nd parameter.

```
agree() {
  return this.HttpClient.put(`${this.apiUrl}/agreeEula/`, null);
}
```